# In what way .NET is a framework?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I'm trying to grasp the concept of *Framework* for too long now. All the sources in the net 
pretty much say the same thing. From what i got so far:

A Framework is something that helps a programmer to develop applications by providing some common functionalities
such as hardware management etc. 
The main difference between a framework and a library the concept of *Inversion of control*: in a library, it's you from your code that calls the library functions, wheres in frameworks, it's the framework that controls the flow of control of the program, 
 you just supply some callback functions and the framework will call them when it's time.

I'm trying to collect a bunch of examples that share some resemblance to help me understand better what exactly a framework is.

So i'm trying to understand: In what way .NET is a framework? and can someone explain in what way it's similar to other frameworks such as Flask, Java Collections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .net is a framework, it can be similar to many things. Dotnet uses the c# and it's based on MVC pattern. You should search for MVC pattern and it's usage. Dotnet is developed by Microsoft and current version is 5.0 (i'm not sure). Also you may want to search about .net core. It has similarities and differences with .net.